# MySQL log file configuration

Tags: mysql, logging

I'm having problems with my configuration log file. I'm using windows and mysql run as a windows service (my tomcat loads it).

My configuration file:

```
general_log_file        = C:\mysql.log
general_log

#Log output can be FILE,TABLE or NONE
log_output = FILE

log_error                = C:\error.log
log-error                = C:\error.log
```

What am I missing? 
I tried configuring using the MySQL workbench but sometimes it works and some times it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

> general_log=1
>   general_log_file =general-query.log
>
> log_error=error.log

Try with this configuration, you can find out more details here:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-log.html

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/error-log.html